# Json-file and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a json file so that data can be saved from another program and stored for later use. I want to create a dictionary for a team, and want to be able to chose a player and be able to see the players progression in 1RM squats.

But the problem is that I do not know how to add more values to 'date' and '1RM squats' and how to pick them out so that they can be plotted against each other.

This is what I got so far:

```
team_name=json.dumps({ 'Maja':
                        {'date':'2019-11-12',
                        '1RM squat(kg)':50},
                        'Sofia':
                        {'date':'2019-11-12',
                        '1RM squat(kg)':55},
                        'David':
                        {'date':'2019-11-17',
                        '1RM squat(kg)':90},
                        'Martin':
                        {'date':'2019-11-10',
                        '1RM squat(kg)': 100},
                        'Hanna':
                        {'date':'2019-10-20',
                        '1RM squat(kg)':120}})

y=json.loads(team_name)
#creates data frame to get an output easier to read
df=pd.DataFrame(y)
print (df)
```

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation for Pandas, the JSON module, dictionaries, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example:

```
import json

team_name=json.dumps({ 'Maja':
                        {'date':'2019-11-12',
                        '1RM squat(kg)':50},
                        'Sofia':
                        {'date':'2019-11-12',
                        '1RM squat(kg)':55},
                        'David':
                        {'date':'2019-11-17',
                        '1RM squat(kg)':90},
                        'Martin':
                        {'date':'2019-11-10',
                        '1RM squat(kg)': 100},
                        'Hanna':
                        {'date':'2019-10-20',
                        '1RM squat(kg)':120}})

y=json.loads(team_name)
#changing the value of date
y["Maja"]["date"] = "2019-12-12"
print (y["Maja"]["date"])
```

> You can also check the documentation on https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html